# Weird integration

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int\frac{v}{(v+1)^2}dv=\int xdx$$

I saw this question in a math site. I don't have any idea to solve this. Can anyone guide me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the question?

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

$$\frac{v}{(v+1)^2}=\dfrac{v+1-1}{(v+1)^2}=\dfrac1{v+1}-\dfrac1{(v+1)^2}$$

Or set $v+1=u\implies dv=du$